# R programming language - Loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a final coming up really soon, here are some examples the teacher has posted but really can't understand it.

1.`for` and `next`

```
 for(i in 1:3)
   {
    print("a")
    next
    print("b")
   }
```

prints

```
[1] "a"
[1] "a"
[1] "a"
```

2.Nested `for`

How does the next statement work here ? It continues to loop if some condition is set I know, example `(if i==3) {next}` so I ignore the proceeds with `i=3` but how does it work when it is not under a condition ? searched all the web but couldn't find an answer

```
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:3)
    for(k in j:i)
      print("*")
}
```

The code above produces 17 stars. How ?

3.Another mystery

```
my.vector <- c(1,5,9,13)
my.data <- c()
for(i in my.vector){
  if(i <= 5){
    my.data <- c(my.data, "small")
  }else{
    my.data <- c(my.data, "huge")
  }
  my.data <- c(my.data, i)
}
```

The output of the code above is "9","huge","13"

Seriously how ? Shouldn't it be "small","small","huge","huge" ?

Comment: Tell the teacher they should stop teaching you to grow objects in a loop. There are usually better alternatives to `for` loops in R, but if you use them, preallocate the return object. Regarding `next`: Since it is always called the code always jumps to the next iteration. The code coming after it is always ignored (thus this example is kind of stupid). I don't even know why they teach you `next`. In more than five years of using R I have never used `next`.

Comment: A great method for working out these types of problems on you own is to insert additional print statements like `print(i)` to track the movement in the loops.

Answer (score 3):

1. From R help for control flow: next halts the processing of the current iteration and advances the looping index. So after printing "a", it restarts from the beginning of the for loop while adding the index by 1.
2. When i = j (3 occasions), 3 stars are produced; when |i-j| = 1 (4 occasions), 4*2 stars are produced; and when |i-j| = 2 (2 occasions), 2*3 stars are produced. In total, 3 + 8 + 6 = 17 stars.
3. My output is:
   "small" "1"     "small" "5"     "huge"  "9"     "huge"  "13"

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, consider that:

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
    print("a")
    if(TRUE){next}
    print("b")
}
```

Is essentially equivalent. Its saying "well this is always going to be true anyway". Then it should help with your understanding why it doesn't print "b".

For the second one...well write each step out. Just through a bunch of print(i), print (j) and it should make sense why.

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    for (k in j:i) {
      #print("*")
      print(i)
      print(j)
      print(k)          
      print(" ")
    }
  }
}
```

For the last one...well I get `"small" "small" "huge" "huge"` so I'm not sure why it doesn't match my output.

And you should be avoiding `for` loops in R like a plague...try anything from the `apply` family.